# How does QueryCursor works

Tags: java, sql, ignite

```
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql)) {
  for (List<?> row : cursor)
    System.out.println("ROW :: " + row.get(0));
}
```

Does cursor go to database and fetch list by list or does it contains the whole data.

```
QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sqlQuery))
```

Comment: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries) noted by [Joakim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson):

> QueryCursor represents query result set and allows for transparent page-by-page iteration. Whenever user starts iterating over the last page, it will automatically request the next page in the background. For cases when pagination is not needed, you can use QueryCursor.getAll() method which will fetch the whole query result and store it in a collection.

Comment: Note that you need to allow lazy query execution by supplying `lazy=true`, else the whole result set will be held on heap at once on reducer server node, even if supplied to client on per page basis.